# Move static block on category page

Tags: magento2, layout, category

I'm trying to have 2 pieces of static content on a category page. One directly beneath the category title and another below the product listings. I notice Categories have a "description" and support a static block, so my plan is to use "description" for one section of text and a static block for the other.

The problem I'm having is moving the static block with a layout update. What I'm doing is using the `identifier` of the static block and a layout update like this:

`<move element="test-category-block" destination="content" after="-"/>`

However the static block is not moving. Any idea why not?

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the base `catalog_category_view.xml` file in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`:

```
<referenceContainer name="columns.top">
    <container name="category.view.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="category-view" after="-">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.image" template="Magento_Catalog::category/image.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.description" template="Magento_Catalog::category/description.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.cms" template="Magento_Catalog::category/cms.phtml"/>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

In accordance with that, changing the layout update from the identifier of the static block to `category.cms` solved it.